# Regex match all excluding a delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex, prismjs

I have two sample strings of code like so:

```js
"const x = anything;"
"const {a, b, c, d} = anything;"
```

I want to match `x`, as well as `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` (none of which are literal, they can be any valid JavaScript variable character(s), but are delimited by commas) if they are preceded by the keyword `const`. The latter is the destructuring syntax.

Context: this is to extend syntax highlighting of code tokens in PrismJS.

What I've tried so far:

```js
  Prism.languages.insertBefore(lang, 'operator', {
    constant: {
      pattern: /(const\s?{?)[\s_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF,]*(?!:)/,
      lookbehind: true,
    },
  });
```

The comma is inside the `[]`, and I am not sure of how to "continue" matching each variable inside the braces **without** including the comma character.

Comment: Why do you use only `const` ?

Comment: The goal is to not color `var` and `let` variables, only `const` ones, for semantic reasons.

Comment: Maybe [`/(?<=const\s+)[$\w]+|(?<=const\s*{[^{}]*)[$\w]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/3Zfrsb/1)? Not sure it will work in Prism though.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `$\w` is too restrictive for [variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/what-characters-are-valid-for-javascript-variable-names).

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I only cared to create a PoC pattern, enhancing is always the last step. If that expression works, the rest is just a matter of adding the finishing touch. It is not an answer.

Comment: I don't think global matches work with Prism unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```regex
(?:const\s+{?\s*)[_$\w]+(?:[,}\s])
```

I'll try and improve it by replacing `\w` to match identifiers using non-alphanumeric characters. Possibly:

```regex
(?:const\s+{?\s*)[_$\p{L}]+(?:[,}\s])
```